# Hosting WCF Service that accesses SQL database onto IIS

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that accesses a SQL database to fetch data . I would like to deploy this service onto IIS . However , when i do this , my service is not able to access the database .
This is how my service accesses the DB

```
    SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"user id=SAIESH\Saiesh Natarajan;" +
                                   "password=;server=SAIESH\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=master; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");
```

I need to know what i should do to be able to access this DB from my WCF service hosted on IIS

Comment: Where is the database in relation to the web server? Are there firewalls possibly in the way? is your sqlexpress setup for remote connections?

Comment: Well, for one - **either** you specify a UserId/password, **or** you define a `Trusted_Connection` (or `Integrated Security`) to use the current credentials - but you **should not** define both in the same connection string

Comment: I tried running the service locally using it's localhost URL assigned by default by VS10 and not from IIS and it works fine only when both the UserId/password AND trusted_connection are included . I realize something is wrong but am not able to determine what .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under IIS your service usually will be executed under NETWORK SERVICE account. In your connection string you use `trusted_connection=yes`. So, you need grant access to NETWORK SERVICE account. But better solution is to change authentication scheme and use USERNAME/PASSWORD to connect to SQL server.
Actually here is similar question [WCF Impersonation and SQL trusted connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662902/wcf-impersonation-and-sql-trusted-connections)

Comment: Thank you paramosh . I added my own Domain account and now it works .